# How to list all exported functions from a shared object in C

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I can use `objdump -T` to get a list of all exported symbols from an elf. How can I implement it myself in C. For example, I guess I can use libelf somehow, but it appears to be poorly documented.

Comment: You asked about `libelf` (which _can_ be used on ELF platforms) but you didn't tag your question with `elf` or `linux`. Solutions for non-ELF platforms will be different. Which platform(s) do you care about?

Comment: You can read objdump source code from inspiration. Start here https://github.com/CyberGrandChallenge/binutils/blob/master/binutils/objdump.c#L3576 .